# How to disable page scroll while scrolling div

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane

[image: Scrollers]

Hello guys,

I have a problem disabling page scroll while user is scrolling the div (black squared scrollbar). I need to disable the page scroll when user's mouse is inside the scrolling div (that with images inside).

I've tried setting overflow: hidden; to body but it works not the good (as page scrollbars become gray/disabled).

I use jScrollPane for custom scrollbar in the block.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the above page? Or add HTML/CSS code related to this page.

Comment: Sorry, I can't as it's a private project. And HTML+CSS+JS is too large.

Comment: Anyway, the point is that there's a block with jscrollpane attach, and a regular scrollbar on body.

Comment: No worries. Is this block with jScrollPane located within a div or p tags?

Comment: Try to apply the "overflow: hidden;" in the div tag, instead in the body.

Comment: Same problem for me, when i scroll using the mousewheel, the body scroll too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could be your solution (anyway, your problem is old now) but you may try this : the page scroll occurs when the max scroll of a div is reached. My solution is to force the div to never reach this max scroll.

```
$(".scrollable").scroll(function(){
    var maxScrollTop = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).outerHeight();
    if($(this).scrollTop() == maxScrollTop){
        $(this).scrollTop(maxScrollTop - 1);
    }
});
```

This trick works fine for me.